# VB6 overflow error with large integers

Tags: vb6, integer, overflow

I am trying to set an integer value as such:

```
Dim intID as integer
intID = x * 10000
```

This works ok when `x` is 3 or less. But when `x` is 4, this gives me the error:

> run-time error 6 
>   Overflow

I don't understand why this is. I can set `intID` to 40000 directly without any problems, so it's obviously capable of storing large numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You *cannot* set a vb6 integer to 40000 as they are signed 16 bit numbers so +32767 is the maximum.

`Long` is the 32 bit type.

However as a caveat, if you were to:

```
Dim lngID As Long
lngID = 4 * 10000
```

You would still get an overflow as literal numbers default to Integer, to correct that just type one as long with `&` or cast one as long using `CLng()`:

```
Dim lngID As Long
lngID = 4 * 10000&
lngID = 4 * CLng(10000)
```

**Update**:

[image]

Comment: In vb**6**, `Dim intID as integer: intID = 40000` will error 100% of the time

Comment: Because `3 * 10000` fits in an integer (its < 32767), `4 * 10000` does not

Comment: @Urbycoz the great majority of your questions have been about **VB.NET** . For the avoidance of any doubt, could you confirm that you are definitely seeing this behaviour in **VB6** ?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely VB6. I'll post a screenshot.

Comment: @Alex- You're right. It's behaving as you say for me now. Not sure what changed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11):

in VB6, the Integer type is a whole number which ranges from -32768 to 32767.

You would be best using the `Long` type here.

Answer (score 1):

In VB Integer variable range is -32,768 to 32,767 If any variable value is more than this range in your program,you have to declare Data type Long instead of Integer.

```
Dim intID as integer
intID = x * 10000

Dim lngID AS Long

lngID = x * CLng(10000)
' if 10000
' whatever you want to be
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. You have simply posted the code.

Comment: In VB Integer variable range is -32,768 to 32,767                                                                                                           If any variable value is more than this range in your program,you have to declare Data type Long instead of Integer.Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Always Beginner, welcome to Stack Overflow. You are right, the correct way to solve this is to use a long instead of an int. Thank you for providing this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In VB Integer variable range is -32,768 to 32,767 If any variable value is more than this range in your program.
Please declare variable in long if your count is more than 32767 then not given any error in your program.

```
Dim lngid AS long
```