# Is it possible to improve or shorten this C function?

Tags: c

Is it possible to improve this function?

Purpose: given a memory address in Augend and a memory offset in addend shall return the long value of this memory address

```
TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT long __stdcall MemI4Get(unsigned long Augend, unsigned long Addend) {
    return (long)(unsigned long*)*(unsigned long*)(Augend + Addend);
}
```

Comment: It can probably be improved, but not without knowing more context. What is the *actual* and *original* problem this function is supposed to solve? Why is the address passed as an `unsigned long` value? Is this for a 32- or 64-bit system? Is `Addend` a byte-offset or more like an array index? And why do you first dereference the pointer result of `(unsigned long*)(Augend + Addend)` just to directly convert it to a pointer again? There's a lot of things that doesn't make sense.

Comment: It is not known if `Augend` is aligned for `long`. Actually it is not a memory address.

Comment: I am C beginner, sorry. It is a function used in old classic VB, where only signed longs are available. To avoid pointer addition errors there I call this function to add a pointer address fetched there by VarPtr with an offset to get the long memory value. So I get my old programm ready for 4GB address space.

Comment: **(unsigned long*)(Augend + Addend);
Seems to be enough to do the job

Comment: I am C beginner, sorry. It is a function used in old classic VB, where only signed longs are available. To avoid pointer addition errors there I call this function to add a pointer address fetched there by VarPtr with an offset to get the long memory value. So I get my old programm ready for 4GB address space. You know, when there is an addition of an offset to a signed long in VB, you may get an overflow error, even the memory address is valid 0x7FFFFFFF+1 is overflow

Comment: So I call this function with 0x7FFFFFFF and offset 1 and have in c++ a unsigned addition, and I fetch the memory of 0x80000000

Comment: How are you doing direct memory access on a PC anyway? That hasn't really been feasible since Windows 98 somewhere (the time when people still used VB I guess).

Comment: Just noticing: Overflow *does* [result in errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895816/vb6-overflow-error-with-large-integers) (seems so at least).

Comment: In fact when you make an unsigned long addition in C++ and you return the result
```
TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT long __stdcall ULongAdd(unsigned long Augend, unsigned long Addend)
{
    return Augend + Addend;
}
```
and you call this in VB6 
Public Declare Function ULongAdd Lib "TCEOLEHelp.dll" (ByVal P As Long, ByVal off As Long) As Long
you get in result a negative signed long  when calling this with 0x7FFFFFFF, 1000
But for memory access this is irrelevant

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, direct memory access in classic VB isn't a basic feature
You can make your own functions in C++ or by using the famous typelib http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/i_VBVM6Lib.html
which is using calls of the VB runtime

Comment: @Aconcagua Just adding is giving me the address but I wanted to get the 4 Byte Long Value of the address. 
This value can be fetched only by 
return (Asterisc)(unsigned long (Asterisc))(Augend + Addend);
in my tries (crazy editor here).

Comment: I think this is better suited for [codereview.se]...

Comment: `long result; memcpy(&result, (void *)((uintptr_t)Augend + Addend)), sizeof(result)); return result;`

Answer (score 1):

check here, it may be helpfull

```
long MemI4Get(unsigned long Augend, unsigned long Addend) {
unsigned long* memoryAddress = (unsigned long*)(Augend + Addend);
return (long)(*memoryAddress);
}
```

Comment: Click where? There's no link. And I'm not sure if reading the memory is intended, actually appears more likely to me that simply a pointer offset should have been calculated and the memory access was introduced by accident (due to little C knowledge?).

Answer (score 1):

For reading the memory value at an address with offset you can simply do this:

```
long __stdcall memI4Get(long address, long offset)
{
    return *(long*)((unsigned long)address + (unsigned long)offset);
}
```

Splitting above one-liner into single-step-by-line code for explanation:

```
address += offset;               // calculate the address actually to read
long* pointer = (long*) address; // create a pointer – right away to the
                                 // type you want to read!
long value = *pointer;           // dereference the pointer,
                                 // i.e. read the memory at the address
return value;                    // (self-explaining...)
```

Note that the explaining variant skipped the casts – they are actually necessary as signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour in C. Still *unsigned* integer overflow might occur (like adding 1 to `0xffffffff`), question remains open how you want to handle that (coming to later).

Note, too, that this variant creates an offset *byte-wise*! If this is what you intend (i.e. having two longs in an array and you want to read the second one via pointer to first one, then `offset` needs to be set to 4), above is fine. If you want to have an offset of 1 instead, then you need to modify:

```
return *((long*)address + offset);
```

This time we *first* produce a pointer, then apply the offset. Background is that in C pointers are moved according to the underlying type, thus in given case we move to next `long` (automatically applying an offset of `offset * sizeof(long)` to the pointer's raw value).

This variant might be more suitable if you actually intend to access arrays in memory.

In either case you might still want to catch the *unsigned* overflow!

```
unsigned long addr = (unsigned long)address + (unsigned long)offset * sizeof(long);
// makes this variant equivalent to second one above:               ^
// drop the multiplication if you need first one
// actually the multiplication might overflow as well!
// not adding a test here, assuming your offsets will
// always be small enough

if(addr < (unsigned long)address)
{
    // this occurs on overflow; then the sum is always smaller
    // than both operands, checking one suffices...
    
    // TODO: error handling!
}
return *(long*)addr;
```

On detecting overflow some appropriate error handling is required! As C doesn't provide any kind of exception handling as e.g. in C++ we could instead opt for:

- an additional output parameter (pointer) that, if non-null,
  either receives the error indicator or the output value
- a struct as return value containing both actual value and indicator
- returning a specific sentinel value indicating the error condition; however that disallows storing exactly this value in memory, so possibly unsuitable.

Comment: Good explanation. Of course overflow might happen and should be catched by caller. Because I use it in classic VB, which is 32 bit only (shame on you, Microsoft!), an overflow will happen early. The DLL for this code should be 32bit compiled as well.

Comment: When adding offset to a Pointer and getting in result > 0xFFFFFFFF I am out of 4GB address space anyway.

Comment: @RenéRössler The point is: with 32-bit long (you'd have to be on e.g. 64-bit linux to have a 64-bit long…) you *cannot* get a value > 0xffffffff – trying to create one results in overflow and wrapping around, getting a result smaller than. And this might even result in a valid address pointing to some entirely different place than what you intended. You actually have two options: 1. Leaving responsibility not to produce overflow to the user providing the arguments (just document what unsuitable values might provoke) and not care further about. 2. Provide some proper error handling mechanism.

Comment: For option 2 I changed my answer, by the way, as 0 as return value indeed is a pretty bad sentinel, that value is far too common regularly (noticing we're not returning addresses, but values…).

Answer (score 1):

Have shortened it without using a variable

```
TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT  long __stdcall CompareMemory(const void* buf1, const void* buf2, size_t count)
{
    return memcmp(buf1, buf2, count);
}

typedef long(__stdcall* FUNCPTR)();
typedef long(__stdcall* FUNCPTR1)(long);
typedef long(__stdcall* FUNCPTR2)(long, long);
typedef long(__stdcall* FUNCPTR3)(long, long, long);
typedef long(__stdcall* FUNCPTR4)(long, long, long, long);
typedef long(__stdcall* FUNCPTR5)(long, long, long, long, long);
typedef long(__stdcall* FUNCPTR6)(long, long, long, long, long, long);


TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT  long __stdcall Callback(void* ptr)
{
    FUNCPTR vbFunc;
    vbFunc = (FUNCPTR)ptr;
    return vbFunc();
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT  long __stdcall Callback1(void* ptr, long p1)
{
    FUNCPTR1 vbFunc;
    vbFunc = (FUNCPTR1)ptr;
    return vbFunc(p1);
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT  long __stdcall Callback2(void* ptr, long p1, long p2)
{
    FUNCPTR2 vbFunc;
    vbFunc = (FUNCPTR2)ptr;
    return vbFunc(p1, p2);
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT  long __stdcall Callback3(void* ptr, long p1, long p2, long p3)
{
    FUNCPTR3 vbFunc;
    vbFunc = (FUNCPTR3)ptr;
    return vbFunc(p1, p2, p3);
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT  long __stdcall Callback4(void* ptr, long p1, long p2, long p3, long p4)
{
    FUNCPTR4 vbFunc;
    vbFunc = (FUNCPTR4)ptr;
    return vbFunc(p1, p2, p3, p4);
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT  long __stdcall Callback5(void* ptr, long p1, long p2, long p3, long p4, long p5)
{
    FUNCPTR5 vbFunc;
    vbFunc = (FUNCPTR5)ptr;
    return vbFunc(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT  long __stdcall Callback6(void* ptr, long p1, long p2, long p3, long p4, long p5, long p6)
{
    FUNCPTR6 vbFunc;
    vbFunc = (FUNCPTR6)ptr;
    return vbFunc(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6);
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT long __stdcall ULongAdd(unsigned long Augend, unsigned long Addend)
{
    return Augend + Addend;
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT long __stdcall ULongSub(unsigned long Augend, unsigned long Addend)
{
    return Augend - Addend;
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT long __stdcall MemI4Get(unsigned long Augend, unsigned long Addend)
{
    return *(unsigned long*)(Augend + Addend);
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT short __stdcall MemI2Get(unsigned long Augend, unsigned long Addend)
{
    return *(unsigned short*)(Augend + Addend);
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT unsigned char __stdcall MemI1Get(unsigned long Augend, unsigned long Addend)
{
    return *(unsigned char*)(Augend + Addend);
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT void __stdcall MemI4Set(unsigned long Augend, unsigned long Addend, long Value)
{
    *(unsigned long*)(Augend + Addend) = Value;
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT void __stdcall MemI2Set(unsigned long Augend, unsigned long Addend, short Value)
{
    *(unsigned short*)(Augend + Addend) = Value;
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT void __stdcall MemI1Set(unsigned long Augend, unsigned long Addend, unsigned char Value)
{
    *(unsigned char*)(Augend + Addend) = Value;
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT void __stdcall Inc4(unsigned long* Augend)
{
    *Augend+=4;
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT void __stdcall Dec4(unsigned long* Augend)
{
    *Augend -= 4;
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT void __stdcall Inc1(unsigned long* Augend)
{
    *Augend += 1;
}

TCEOLEHELP_DLLEXPORT void __stdcall Dec1(unsigned long* Augend)
{
    *Augend -= 1;
}
```

So if you make with it a DLL in C++ you can use it in classic VB (of course there are not many). Just have added callback functionality (missing in VB to make a module function call by AddressOf), direct memory comparison with two addresses, and the data type of MemI2Get, MemI2Set was wrong (there was int instead of short, int is 4byte type, and that was wrong)

```
Public Declare Function ULongAdd Lib "TCEOLEHelp.dll" (ByVal P As Long, ByVal off As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function MemI4Get Lib "TCEOLEHelp.dll" (ByVal P As Long, ByVal off As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function MemI2Get Lib "TCEOLEHelp.dll" (ByVal P As Long, ByVal off As Long) As Integer
Public Declare Function MemI1Get Lib "TCEOLEHelp.dll" (ByVal P As Long, ByVal off As Long) As Byte
Public Declare Sub MemI4Set Lib "TCEOLEHelp.dll" (ByVal P As Long, ByVal off As Long, ByVal Value As Long)
Public Declare Sub MemI2Set Lib "TCEOLEHelp.dll" (ByVal P As Long, ByVal off As Long, ByVal Value As Integer)
Public Declare Sub MemI1Set Lib "TCEOLEHelp.dll" (ByVal P As Long, ByVal off As Long, ByVal Value As Byte)
Public Declare Sub Inc4 Lib "TCEOLEHelp.dll" (ByRef P As Any)
```

Use it in VB

```
    Dim A As Long
    
    A = 100
    
    Debug.Print MemI4Get(VarPtr(A), 0)  'displays 100
    
    MemI4Set VarPtr(A), 0, 101
    
    Debug.Print A   'displays 101
```